# Adding And subtracting with a twist

Tags: java

It goes like this: The purpose of the Project4Appclass is to create a math game for children to play thatwill strengthen their addition and subtraction skills. In order for the game to allow the student to get enough practice, the game will ask the student 10 questions.  If the student gets the first 10 questions correct, the game should end.  Otherwise, the game should continue until one of two things happen: 1) the student’s percent of correct answers reaches at least 85%, or 2) the student hascompleted 20 questions. When the game ends, the student should be told the number of addition questions he/she got correct and incorrect as well as the number of subtraction questions he/she got correct and incorrect.  It should also give a score which isthe percent of questions he/she got correct. (and use no "Break")

```
package proj3;
import java.util.Random;


public class Question {

private int operand1;
private int operand2;
private char operator;

/**
 * <p> Name: main method </p>
 * 
 */
public Question()
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    boolean random = rand.nextBoolean();

    if(rand.nextBoolean())
    {
        operator = '+';
        operand1 = rand.nextInt(13);
        operand2 = rand.nextInt(13);
    }
    else 
    {
        operator = '-';
        operand1 = rand.nextInt(13 - 6) + 6;
        operand2 = rand.nextInt((operand1 - 0) + 1) + 0;
    }


}
/**
 * getOperand1 method - returns what's stored in the instance variable value
 * @return the state of the instance variable value
 */
public int getOperand1()
{
    return operand1;
}
/**
 * getOperand2 method - returns what's stored in the instance variable value
 * @return the state of the instance variable value
 */
public int getOperand2()
{
    return operand2;
}
/**
 * getOperator method - returns what's stored in the instance variable value
 * @return the state of the instance variable value
 */
public char getOperator()
{
    return operator;
}


 /**
 * toString method - this method returns the state of the Question object
 * @return a reference to a String object that contains 
 * the operands and the operator 
 */
public String toString()
{
    String question;
    question = operand1 + " " + operator + " " + operand2 + " " + "=";
    return question;


}
 /**
 * determineAnswer method - this method returns the state of the card object
 * @return a reference to a Question object that contains the answer to 
 * a random question.
 */
public int determineAnswer()
{
    if(operator == '+')
        return operand1 + operand2;
    else
        return operand1 - operand2;
}
}
```

This is what Project4App currently looks like(stuck on)

```
 public static void main(String [] args)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int percentage = 0;
    int questions = 0;
    while( questions > 10 && questions < 20 && percentage >= 85.0)
    {
        Question q = new Question();
        System.out.println("What is the result?");
        System.out.println(q);
        int answer = scan.nextInt(); 
        if(answer == q.determineAnswer())
            System.out.println("Congratulations, you got it correct!");

        else
            System.out.println("The correct answer for " + q + " is " + q.determineAnswer());

    }



    /**for(int i =0; i <= 20; i++)
    {
        Question q = new Question();
        System.out.println("What is the result?");
        System.out.println(q);
        int answer = scan.nextInt();


        if(answer == q.determineAnswer())
        {
            System.out.println("Congratulations, you got it correct!");

        }
        else
            System.out.println("The correct answer for " + q + " is " + q.determineAnswer());
    }
    **/
}

}
```

Any advice will be appreciated on how to continue.

Comment: Your question is likely not specific enough and the moderators may ask you to refine it.

Comment: You now need to adjust the values of `percentage` and `questions` according to the result of the answer evaluation, so that your loop condition can trigger. You will have to slightly tweak the condition though.

Answer (score 0):

I did not test

```
 boolean isOver = false;
 while( !isOver ){
    questions++;
    Question q = new Question();
    System.out.println("What is the result?");
    System.out.println(q);
    int answer = scan.nextInt(); 
    if(answer == q.determineAnswer())
        System.out.println("Congratulations, you got it correct!");
    else
        System.out.println("The correct answer for " + q + " is "+ q.determineAnswer());

    if( (questions > 10 && percentage >= 85.0) || questions == 20){
        isOver = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will result in an endless loop because both `questions` and `percentage` is never updated.

Comment: added questions++ but you have to calculate percentage

Comment: to calculate percentage add a variable and update every time the answer is correct then devide that by questions